# UNIX: Strange output if piped to less

Tags: unix, command

If I execute ls command with pipe to less, I get strange output

```
ESC[00mESC[00mfile1.ccESC[00m
ESC[00file2.ccESC[00m
ESC[00file3.ccESC[00m
```

(means ESC string in between).

Without ls, the output is:

```
file1.cc    file2.cc    file3.cc
```

How to correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have the `--color=always` option to `ls` set, either through an alias, functions or the `LS_COLORS` environment variable and `ls` is sending color directives to a non-terminal (that is, your pipe to `less`).

Answer (score 3):

Use `less -R` or set the `LESS` environment variable to `-R`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing are ANSI escape sequences for setting colors. Run `ls --color=no`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make less output raw control characters using `less -r`.

Comment: The upper-case option -R avoids some line-breaking problems.